# Cómo crear una Label que diga Abierto o Cerrado (según la hora del día)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Me surgió la duda de cómo hacer que en un Label aparezca la palabra: `Abierto` o `Cerrado` si no se cumple el horario de atención en la oficina.

Ejemplo:

> ```
> Horario:
> Lunes a Viernes 7:30am - 5:30pm
> ```

Si obtengo la hora de visita del usuario a la pagina (`7:20pm`) y no está dentro de ese rango de hora entonces en el Label mostraría `Cerrado`, pero si está en ese horario (`10:45am`) se mostraría `Abierto`.

Hasta el momento tengo el .cs de la siguiente manera, pero no hallo agregar el sábado y el domingo, agregué sólo el domingo, pero cuando trato con Sábado me arroja error.

```
var Hoy = DateTime.Today;

DateTime HoraCliente = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,         DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour,DateTime.Now.Minute,          DateTime.Now.Second);
DateTime HoraApertura = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 30, 0);
DateTime HoraCierre = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 17, 30, 0);

Label_Horario.Text = (TimeSpan.Compare(HoraCliente.TimeOfDay, HoraApertura.TimeOfDay) >= 0 && TimeSpan.Compare(HoraCliente.TimeOfDay, HoraCierre.TimeOfDay) <= 0 && Hoy.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) ? 
    "<span class='Open'>Abierto</span><span class='CloseDisabled'> Cerrado</span>" : 
    "<span class='OpenDisabled'>Abierto</span><span class='Close'> Cerrado</span>";
```

Comment: ¿Solo obtienes la hora de la visita, o el día también, y en qué formato? Porque si solo recibes la hora, ¿como puedes verificar si es un fin de semana para decir que está cerrado sin importar la hora?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón no pensé en los días de la semana ni en los festivos, eso generaría un gran problema no? Como incluyo todos los días de fiesta si son muy variables? ya me preocupé XD

Comment: Manejar días festivos siempre es un problema, porque verificar el 25 de diciembre por ejemplo, eso es fácil. Pero ciertos días festivos no caen la misma fecha a cada año. Sé que algunos manejan esto usando una tabla de días festivos en una base de datos que tienen que mantener al día con el paso de los años.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediante `TimeSpan.Compare` enlace documentación msdn Microsfot: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Lo que buscamos es que la hora del cliente sea mayor o igual a la de apertura de la oficina y menor o igual a la de cierre por lo que `TimeSpan.Compare` regresa 0 si es igual, 1 si es mayor y -1 si es menor.

```
DateTime TCliente = new DateTime(2017, 3, 31, 9, 28, 0);
DateTime TApertura = new DateTime(2017, 3, 31, 7, 30, 0);
DateTime TCierre = new DateTime(2017, 3, 31, 17, 30, 0);

TuLabel.Text = (TimeSpan.Compare(TCliente.TimeOfDay, TApertura.TimeOfDay) >= 0 && TimeSpan.Compare(TCliente.TimeOfDay, TCierre.TimeOfDay) <= 0) ? "Abierto" : "Cerrado";
```

Si la comparación es >= 0 contra apertura de la oficina y <= 0 a la hora de cierre nos indica que el cliente esta en el horario de la tienda colocamos el texto de Abierto de lo contrario Cerrado

Comment: Wow compadre, no lo planié de esa manera estaba tratando por TimeSpan y haciendo Arrays pero sin exito.
Muchas Gracias por la ayuda!
Ahora solo debo buscar el como pasar la fecha fija a una fecha Dinamica, pero ya tengo por donde empezar.

Comment: Puedes usar DateTime TApertura = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 30, 0); por ejemplo, Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Asumiendo que partes de una fecha de tipo `DateTime`, determinar si está "abierto" se puede determinar con 4 condiciones sencillas:

1. La fecha no cae un sábado
2. La fecha no cae un domingo
3. La hora es igual o mayor a 7:30am
4. La hora es igual o menor a 5:30pm

Si la fecha cumple con las 4 condiciones, quiere decir que está "abierto", de lo contrario, está "cerrado".

En código, esto se podría expresar de esta forma:

```
DateTime fecha = ???

bool abierto = fecha.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                && fecha.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
                && fecha.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(7, 30, 0)   // 7:30 am
                && fecha.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0); // 5:30 pm

Console.WriteLine(abierto ? "abierto" : "cerrado");
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/VFU59389)</kbd>

Comment: hola Compa, veras probé con este y no me funcionó como se esperaría o de hecho no me funcionó hay que agregarle algún fragmento Obvio que yo no sepa?

Comment: No te puedo decir, porque no sé como hicistes la prueba. Aquí te dejo un enlace con una demo en vivo para que veas como funciona: http://rextester.com/VFU59389.

Answer (score 2):

Es un lindo ejercicio para practicar, aqui va mi solucion:

```
using System;

namespace labelTemporizada
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DateTime ahora = DateTime.Now;
        string label = "cerrado";
        if (DiasApertura(ahora) && HorarioApertura(ahora))
        {
            label = "abierto";
        }
    }

    private static bool HorarioApertura(DateTime ahora)
    {
        bool horarioLaboral = false;

        TimeSpan apertura = new TimeSpan(7, 30, 0);
        TimeSpan cierre = new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0);
        if (ahora.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(apertura) >= 0 && ahora.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(cierre) <= 0)
        {
            horarioLaboral = true;
        }
        return horarioLaboral;
    }

    private static bool DiasApertura(DateTime ahora)
    {
        bool diaLaboral = false;
        switch (ahora.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                diaLaboral = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return diaLaboral;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu propuesta Urruestarazu, es una buena alternativa también.